# Echo <svg> element in a class when condition is met in php function

Tags: php, html, svg

I've got a Simple piece of [php](/questions/tagged/php) code combined with some [html](/questions/tagged/html).

What i want to do is as follow:

I've got a php class defining some properties in my code.
Class - Statuses

Variables of "Statuses" - Circle, size, color.

I want to link an svg element that gives the size and and radius of the circle and then the color as well.

I've got a function that when it is met, an [if](/questions/tagged/if) statement will then need to display the class circle with a size and color depending on the condition that is met.

Here is the class:

```
<?php

class Statuses
{

var $circle;
var $size;
var $color;

public function print_condition()
{
    echo $this->circle;
    echo $this->size;
    echo $this->color;
}

public function condition($circle, $size, $color)
{
    $this->circle = $circle;
    $this->size = $size;
    $this->color = $color;
}

}

$daily = new Statuses;

$daily->condition("height=\"300\" width=\"300\"", "cx=\"150\" cy=\"150\" r=\"100\"", "stroke=\"black\" stroke-width=\"3\" fill=\"green\"");

$daily->print_condition();
```

Here is the function:

```
<?php
function funcName()
{
if (condition) {
    echo "I want to echo the 'daily' variable here";

} else {
    echo "I want to echo the 'none' variable here";

}
}
```

and Here is the svg elements:

```
  <div id="circles">

<svg id="green" height="300" width="300">
    <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="green" />
</svg>
<br>
<svg id="orange" height="300" width="300">
    <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="orange" />
</svg>
<br>
<svg id="red" height="300" width="300">
    <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>

</div>
```

I'm not sure how to get the svg element to display properly in the variable and i'm not sure how to invoke the variable in my function either.

Your advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your naming convention makes it very difficult to understand your intentions, although I believe the following is what you need. Essentially you're trying to hard to cut corners.

Each "statuses" has a set of variables that make is a circle as defined in your svg. Just edit your class to include these as such and rename your variables.

```
<?php

class myCircle
{

$name;
$height;
$width;
$cx;
$cy;
$r;
$stroke;
$stroke-width;
$fill;

private function _print()
{
    echo "<svg id='$this->name' height='$this->height' width='$this->width'>
    <circle cx='$this->cx' cy='$this->cy' r='$this->r' stroke='$this->stroke' stroke-width='$this->stroke-width' fill='$this->fill' />
    </svg>";
}

private function _set($name, $height, $width, $cx, $cy, $r, $stroke, $stroke-width, $fill)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->height = $height;
    $this->width = $width;
    $this->cx = $cx;
    $this->cy = $cy;
    $this->r = $r;
    $this->stroke = $stroke;
    $this->stroke-width = $stroke-width;
    $this->fill = $fill;
    }

}
```

End of Class.

You've omitted what exactly your $condition is, so I've not included it in my answer. But to fulfil that and then use your class, you simply have to do the following :

(either have your myCircle class on the same php page, or include it, and then)

```
<div id="circles">
<?php if($condition){
    $daily = new myCircle;
    $daily->_set("testCircle", "300", "300", "150", "150", "100", "black", 3, "green");
    $daily->_print();
  }else{
// Nothing?
} ?>
<div>
```

Or for your three circles :

```
<?php     
$circles = array("green", "orange" "red");    
?>

<div id="circles">

<?php 
if($condition){
for($i = 0; $i < count($circles); $i++){
    $daily = new myCircle;
    $daily->_set($circles[$i], "300", "300", "150", "150", "100", "black", 3, $circles[$i]);
    $daily->_print();
  }
} else{
// Do nothing 
}
?> 
</div>
```

Comment: You've just put a big smile on my face, thanks a lot @cmprogram!

I'm sorry about my naming conventions making it difficult to understand the question, as I mentioned I am still new in coding but i'll make an effort to correct the naming and proper syntax use in future posts and code i write.

You've been a huge help sir.

Comment: @AlexCoetzee Absolutely no problem at all. A big tip for if you're new : name your variables and classes whatever you want, ideally something memorable or that means something to you. Ignore advice that says you should make it succinct, that can come later. What's more important, is you understand the concept, and what's actually going on. Good luck!

Comment: I had 2 problems when working with the code, they kept giving error code undefined variable Sir @cmprogram. I corrected them, if you'd like can edit your post and include the fixes?

Comment: What were the undefined variables?

Comment: echo "<svg id='$name' height='$height' width='$width'>
    <circle cx='$cx' cy='$cy' r='$r' stroke='$stroke' stroke-width='$stroke-width' fill='fill' />
    </svg>"; 

Needed to change it to

 echo "<svg id=\"$this->name\" height=\"$this->height\" width=\"$this->width\">
        <circle cx=\"$this->cx\" cy=\"$this->cy\" r=\"$this->r\" stroke=\"$this->stroke\" stroke-width=\"$this->stroke_width\" fill=\"$this->fill\" />
    </svg>";

Comment: @AlexCoetzee You're absolutely right. Laziness on my part. Amended.

Comment: Awesome, but thanks a million for helping me out Sir.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this: (I assume you get the values for the color and size variables dynamically.)

```php
$size = 300;
$color = "orange";

echo '<svg id="'.$color.'" height="'.$size.'" width="'.$size.'">
    <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="'.$color.'" />
</svg>';
```

Also, instead of echoing you may save the svg in a variable and use it where you need.

```php
$size = 300;
$color = "orange";

$theSVG = '<svg id="'.$color.'" height="'.$size.'" width="'.$size.'">
    <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="'.$color.'" />
</svg>';
```

and then:

```
<?php
function funcName()
{
if (condition) {
   echo $theSVG;

} else {
    echo "";

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million, this was really helpful.

Would you have some input on my second part of the question as well possibly. Where i ask How to use the variable $daily in my function. The problem i'm getting is that when i try and use the variable in my function it says "Undefined variable $daily"

Sorry for the rather newbie questions but I'm still new and trying my best to get the hang of everything.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I hope this is what you were asking